# Add text to each cell of a particular column of an existing excel file with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-3.6, openpyxl

I'm really new to python and I'm stuck with this problem. How can I add text to each cell of say column F of an existing excel file to access link to the financial report? 
Example: Row 2, column F contains edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt
I want to add "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/" to form a financial report link i.e. 
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt

I tried using pandas/openpyxl but I'm not able to modify the sheet at all.
Is there any other module or anything? My code looks something like this

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_excel('cik_list.xlsx')
sheet = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl')
sheet['SECFNAME'] = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/' + 
sheet['SECFNAME'].astype(str)
sheet.save()
```

And I get this error :
TypeError: '_Openpyxl22Writer' object is not subscriptable

I know this might be the easiest one but I really couldn't find anything related. Please help!

Comment: Since `file` is your dataframe, you need to use `file["SECFNAME"]` to access your column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('cik_list.xlsx')
df['SECFNAME'] = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/' + df['SECFNAME']
df.to_excel('fileName.xlsx')
```

This is what is happening here:

1. Reading the excel file to a dataframe
2. Selecting the `SECFNAME` column in the dataframe and appending the string to every row
3. Save to the dataframe to a new file. (Saving the output file with the same name will replace the previous file.)

Comment: Wow!It worked. Thank you so much!  :) i was stuck for a few days.

Comment: The data has shifted one column to the right. How can I remove that? I mean I can just remove it in excel file but is there any way I keep the same number of columns using Python?

Comment: Try doing `df.to_excel("filename.xlsx",index=False)`

Comment: @SDayal No problem mate