# Add text to each cell of a particular column of an existing csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

Please help. I am trying to add links to all the cells in a particular column. Example below

```
columnname
1234
1235
1236
1237

Expected output
https://1234/
https://1235/
https://1236/
https://1237/

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df['columnname'] = 'https:url/' + df['columnname']
df.head(5)
```

I did check [an existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003464/add-text-to-each-cell-of-a-particular-column-of-an-existing-excel-file-with-pyth/70280587#70280587)
and it did not work for me

Comment: "did not work for me": Please provide details

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"columnname": [1234, 1235, 1236, 1237]}) 
df["columnname"] = df["columnname"].apply(lambda x: f"https://{x}/")
```

Comment: Sorry, not working. File "<ipython-input-20-9717e0c9027a>", line 4
    df ["id"] = df["id"].apply(lamda x:f"https://link/")
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame({"id" : [100000, 100001, 100002]})
df ["id"] = df["id"].apply(lamda x: f"https://url/")
df.head(5)